# Why this code from Autodesk help doesn't work?

Tags: c#, api, revit

I am trying to run code from the Autodesk help

http://help.autodesk.com/view/RVT/2014/ENU/?guid=GUID-B6FB80F2-7A17-4242-9E95-D6056090E85B

```
private void CreateViewFilter(Autodesk.Revit.DB.Document doc, View view) 
{
     List<ElementId> categories = new List<ElementId>();
     categories.Add(new ElementId(BuiltInCategory.OST_Walls));
     ParameterFilterElement parameterFilterElement =
       ParameterFilterElement.Create(doc, "Comments = foo", categories);

     FilteredElementCollector parameterCollector = new FilteredElementCollector(doc);
     Parameter parameter = parameterCollector.OfClass(typeof(Wall)).FirstElement().get_Parameter("Comments");

     List<FilterRule> filterRules = new List<FilterRule>();
     filterRules.Add(ParameterFilterRuleFactory.CreateEqualsRule(parameter.Id, "foo", true));
     parameterFilterElement.SetRules(filterRules);

     OverrideGraphicSettings filterSettings = new OverrideGraphicSettings();
     // outline walls in red            
     filterSettings.SetProjectionLineColor(new Color(255, 0, 0));
     view.SetFilterOverrides(parameterFilterElement.Id, filterSettings);
}
```

When I open a view and run the code more than once, I get the following error

> Revit encounterd a argumentException. The given value for name is already in use as a filter element name parmeter name: name at ParameterFilterElement parameterFilterElement = ParameterFilterElement.Create(doc, "Comments= foo", categories). I can't see where this happened in the code.(OBS I change the get_parameter to lookupparameter in the original code above because the first is deprecated)

Comment: What line throws that exception?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](http://www.revitapidocs.com/2017/afa22520-52de-c6b3-fac8-246fe2f8e4fe.htm), the second parameter to the `Create` method is `name`.  The error message states that you are already using the name "Comments = Foo".  So I think your best bet is to dynamically generate the name or provide a way for a user to specify the name.

Answer (score 0):

After a little bit thinking I get it. Actually I should do that from the beginging. Anyway the prgram create filter and It is now in the view so when I run the command again there is already one. Thank you.